# Работа с qiwi в python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Как можно и с помощью каких библиотек реализовать оплату qiwi по ссылке. Требуется получение ссылки на оплату.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял ваш вопрос ,поэтому вот вам:

> *API QIWI* [developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#payments)

Для работы с API вам понадобятся следующие модули:

> *Requests* `pip install requests`->`import requests` ([pypi.org/project/requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/))
>
> *Json* `import json`
>
> > UPD: Ещё покапавшись в недрах сети ,нарыл модуль [qiwi-api](https://pypi.org/project/qiwi-api/)

Comment: Спасибо, думаю с этим разберусь. Но если у кого-то уже есть готовое решение ( Генерация ссылки по которой пользователь может оплатить определенную сумму ) , то прошу скинуть решение сюда.